# eonasdan datetimepicker in modal not able to reset in modal hide event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have the datetimepicker in a modal popup. Everything is working fine except I need to reset all of the widget when the modal opens or closes. What is happening is the widget part does not reset. It opens to the date or time that was selected when it was last used, I have cleared out the text box using a different function. I have tried the following 3 things in all the Bootstrap Modal events: hide, hidden, show and shown.

---

```
 $('.hubDatePicker').data('DateTimePicker').date(moment());
```

---

```
$('.hubDatePicker').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
```

---

```
 $('.hubDatePicker').data('DateTimePicker').destroy(); 

 $(".hubDatePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['MM/DD/YY'],
    allowInputToggle: true
 });
```

---

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing the issue? Your attempts looks resonable and using `show.bs.modal` and `$('.hubDatePicker').data('DateTimePicker').clear();` works for me.